# Use Cordova's Filetransfer plugin with express/blob storage

Tags: node.js, cordova, azure, express

I am using Typescript and Cordova 4.0.

I have the following sample code:

```
    uploadImages(imageUris: Array<string>): any {

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

        for (var i = 0; i < imageUris.length; i++) {
            fileTransfer.upload(imageUris[i], encodeURI('http://3187cf3.ngrok.com/test/photos'), (success) => {
                alert('success');
            }, (err) => {
                alert('error');
            });
        }
    }
```

This corresponds to an express route:

```
var router = express.Router(),
test = test.controller;

router
.post('/test/photos', bind(test.uploadPhotos, test));
```

Which corresponds to a controller method:

```
uploadPhotos(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    console.log(req);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to, inside of my controller, grab the "file" or image I'm posting to my server using Filetransfer. It's not on `req.body` or `req.query`, and when I look through the entire `req` I can't seem to locate the file. The app flow is working enough to actually make the POST request to `test/photos`, I just don't know how to or if I can access the file at that point.

How does Filetransfer work, and how can I access the data I need in my controller so that I can push it to Azure Blob Storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have everything setup correctly to send the data through to your controller. The issue is that you need to put the `file` on the request since cordova's filetransfer plugin doesn't do that by default.

You can do that with a popular library [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

1. `npm install multer --save-dev` To install `multer` and save it to your `package.json` file.
2. In your express config file, add something like the following:

   ```
   var multer = require('multer');

   app.use(multer({ dest: path.resolve(config.root, 'public/img/') }))
   ```

   `'public/img/'` is the path you would like for your image to be saved.
3. Now your `req` will have `files` on it. To upload a single file, you would use `req.files.file`. You'll want to use this variable to send your file to azure's blob storage using something like `blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(containerName, fileName, filePath)`
4. Since you're using Azure for remote storage, chances are you will want to remove the local file that `multer` has saved. I'd recommend using fs or rimraf to remove the file stored in `public/img/`, or whatever you set the path to in your express config. If you are using `fs`, you'll want to use the `.unlink` command.